# "ld: duplicate symbol" issue in XCode cross-compilation

Tags: xcode, opencv, linker-errors, cross-compiling, duplicate-symbol

I am trying to cross-compile a project for the iOS (which is written in windows) and is based on openCV. And then I am trying to use these cross-compiled openCV libs for a specific application (called testApp).

I was first able to successfully cross-compile openCV for the iOS. Then I used these libraries to created another library called testLib.a which was consumed by an application testApp (which also used some openCV functionality).

The testLib.a compiled successfully but, for the testApp I had to add dependency to both testLib.a and the openCV libs (.a files). When I try to compile testApp, I get the following error -

> ld: duplicate symbol cv::split(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat*) in
>   /Users/suri/Projects/testLib/lib/Debug/libopencv_core.a(convert.o) and
>   /Users/suri/Projects/testApp/libs/testLib.a(convert.o) for
>   architecture i386

I can see that this error is probably coming because the openCV libs are added by open testLib as well as testApp. My question is should I try and reorganize the project or is there some other way to fix this issue?

I tried to find where the "split" function might actually be used in testLib but it does not seem to be called. Also, I have checked and every .h in the testLib as well as testApp and they all have a "ifndef" macro.